# Issue in inserting content control with cursor at right position in Office 365 online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to make cursor at right position with space after inserting content control in Office 365 online, but it shows me this error message:

> Sorry, your changes weren't saved. To continue editing this document, please copy your changes and refresh the page.

I lose the changes in the doc if I am trying to insert 4-5 content control quickly in different places of doc having 2-3 pages. It is an intermittent issue.

```
Word.run((context) => {
    var thisDocument = context.document;
    var range = thisDocument.getSelection();
    context.load(range, 'id');
    range.select(Word.SelectionMode.end);
    range = thisDocument.getSelection();
    var instertedControl = range.insertContentControl();
    var insertedText = instertedControl.insertText("controlText", Word.InsertLocation.replace)
    insertedText.font.color = this.ContentControlFontColor;
    instertedControl.title = "controlTitle";
    instertedControl.color = this.ContentControlColor;
    instertedControl.appearance = this.ContentControlAppearance;
    instertedControl.tag = "controlTag";
    context.load(instertedControl, 'id');
    range.select(Word.SelectionMode.end);
    let blankrange = context.document.getSelection();
    var blannkText = blankrange.insertHtml('<font color="black">&nbsp;</font>', Word.InsertLocation.start);
    context.load(blannkText, 'id');
    blankrange.select(Word.SelectionMode.end);
    return context.sync().then(() => {
        //
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your sample using TypeScript and actually i was not able to repro the issue. Give it a try... (please restore in [Script lab](http://aka.ms/scriptlab) using this yaml)

https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/c8dc454e053d264f284054362195eca4